# Adding spring boot jar as a dependency in spring mvc project packaged as war

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project and I want to bundle it with a external war file of a spring framework project, so that when i deploy war the spring boot jar also gets loaded and all controller mappings work.

In simple terms I want to add a spring boot module as a dependency in spring framework module packaged as war.
Is it possible? if yes then how

Thanks

Comment: add the dependency in pom.xml

Comment: not working ..it is not picking up mapping of the boot project

Comment: If the jar is in the classpath and it is not picking means it is not in the scanned path. include the packages to be scanned using @ComponentsToScan